# How to Tile Asp repeator control horizontally

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, css

I am using asp.net repeator control to get pictures from picture library in sp2010. I am able to display it vertically in one row. I now want to tile pictures as follows:
[image]

How do i do that. any help would be appreciated.

Here is the markup

```
<table width="60%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
           <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSearchResults" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSearchResults_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>                                  
    </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
            <td >
            <div>
              <a id="aItemURL" runat="server" href='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.itemURL")%>'>
               <img width="100" height="100" id="imgPhoto" runat="server" src='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.PhotoURL")%>' /></a>        
                  </div>
                 </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: With CSS? What markup is generated?

Comment: code is inserted in the body of this topic. Yes with css or any other methods

Comment: Use DIVs instead of Table. This way you can make it display however using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DIV and applied css.

I wrapped the images around a div and inserted ID called "repeat" with float=left css on the div.

That worked.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I recommend using an ASP.NET [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) instead of the Repeater. You can still specify all the templates like in the case of the Repeater (Header, Footer, Item, Separator, Alternating) but you have more control over the direction of the flow and the number of columns. Check out please the [RepeatDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx), [RepeatLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatlayout.aspx) and [RepeatColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) properties of the control.

In your case I would do:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlistSearchResults" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSearchResults_ItemDataBound" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <HeaderTemplate>                                  
    </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
              <a id="aItemURL" runat="server" href='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.itemURL")%>'>
               <img width="100" height="100" id="imgPhoto" runat="server" src='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.PhotoURL")%>' /></a>        
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

It will automatically fill out the available space horizontally with pictures, and it will continue on the next row when it reached the right margin.

I hope it helped!